# How to underline cells in flextable

Tags: flextable

I have a flextable, and would like to underline a header/cell. Looking through https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/fp_text_default.html, it should be possible, but when I try it out it does not work.

```
set_flextable_defaults(
  font.size = 11, font.color = "#303030",
  padding = 3, table.layout = "autofit")
z <- flextable(head(cars))

z <- compose(
  x = z,
  i = ~ speed < 6,
  j = "speed",
  value = as_paragraph(
    as_chunk("slow... ", props = fp_text_default(color = "red")),
    as_chunk(speed, props = fp_text_default(underlined = TRUE))
  )
)
z
```

returns `Error in as_chunk(speed, props = fp_text_default(underlined = TRUE)) :  object 'speed' not found`

I also tried using style as per https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/format.html:

```
z %>% 
style(i=1,part = "header", pr_t = fp_text_default(underlined = TRUE))
```

but got `Error in UseMethod("plotly_build") :  no applicable method for 'plotly_build' applied to an object of class "flextable"`

as my error

Any suggestions

Comment: you may have loaded purrr and have a conflict with `purrr::compose()`. Try with `mk_par` to avoid this name conflict

Answer (score 2):

You need to detach the package "plotly" from the environment because some functions of "flextable" are also common in "plotly" like style(). I hope it could help.